# OpenGL ES, onDrawFrame performance

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, surface

I have an Activity that I use GLSurfaceView.Renderer in , 
 in the renderer I use onDrawFrame to draw new image on every touch event using glTexImage2D, 
all is fine but when changing the images onDrawFrame the screen pauses for about 1/2 second
can anyone help with this issue?

Activity :

```
onCreate(){..
    glSurfaceView.setRenderer(renderer);
```

....

```
private Renderer renderer = new Renderer() {
```

...

Renderer :

```
onSurfaceCreated(){..
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
```

Renderer :

```
onDrawFrame(){..
if(mytoucheventFired){
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, anotherBitmap, 0);
}
```

Comment: How large are these textures/bitmaps? Is the second bitmap (`anotherBitmap`) already loaded ahead of time, or is that also happening in `onDrawFrame()`?

Answer (score 0):

You might benefit from loading images into textures in native code, i.e. using the NDK, and calling glTexImage2D.  GLUtils.texImage2D might be doing extra per-pixel work to convert the java Bitmap to an OpenGL texture which you can either avoid or accelerate in native code.

glTexImage2D is not traditionally a fast operation.  It might be overkill for you, but if you're willing to go outside the realm of OpenGL, you can beat glTexImage2D in speed by obtaining an address to the underlying texture data and loading directly into it.  On Android (again in native code) you can get the address using an EGL extension called EGL_KHR_image_base:

Some of the key functions you'll need are:

```
EGLImageKHR eglCreateImageKHR(
                        EGLDisplay dpy,
                        EGLContext ctx,
                        EGLenum target,
                        EGLClientBuffer buffer,
                        const EGLint *attrib_list)

EGLBoolean eglDestroyImageKHR(
                        EGLDisplay dpy,
                        EGLImageKHR image)
```

And

```
void glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES(
                        GLenum target,
                        GLeglImageOES image)
```